# How can a map be used to search the list of employe objects on the basis of different parameters?

Tags: java, data-structures, solr, hashmap, trie

I was asked this question in an interview today to which I explained the best to my abilities. But I still don't understand if this is the correct answer.

There is a cache which has Employee object as the key. The cache is populated with data from the database. Now there is a UI where we can enter either or all of the 3 attributes from the Employee object- name, ID and date of joining. Now this search would lead to multiple matching results.  To achieve this we need to check in the cache for the data.

To this I replied saying that my map would be of the structure - >. for the same EmployeeDetails object ,
 I will have multiple keys in the map(EmployeeDetails class is the object which contains complete detail of the Employee including address etc. Employee object just has 3 attributes - name, ID and date of joining.).

One of the objects with only name populated. The other with ID populated and the third one with date of joining populated. And now with the combination of attributes. So the map will be having the following keys -
Employee object with only the name populated -> Value would be list of of all the Employee objects with the same name.
Employee object with only the ID populated ->  Value would be list of of all the Employee objects with the same ID. Ideally the list size in this case should be 1.
Employee objects with only the Date Of Joining -> List of all the employee objects with the same date of joining.

Similarly there would be number of other Employee objects. For one such employee , all the three attributes - name , ID and date of joining would be populated.

In this way, I could have achieved the requirement to display all the employee results in case only some of the attributes out of name, ID and value is set on the UI.

I just want to understand if this is the correct way to achieve the outcome (display of list of matching results on the UI). Since I did not get selected, I believe there is something else which I possibly missed!

Comment: One thing I just want to point you is consider using mutable objects as keys in HashMap structure.. In any where if the object has modified then you will not get the same hash key once again.

Comment: So, how many maps do you have?  7 (id), (name), (id,name), (date), (name,date), etc...?  If so then your scheme is not scalable.  8 fields would blow that up to 255 different maps.   3 or 4? If so then your description is missing a few steps.

Comment: I have 7 keys in the same map. If it is not scalable and the map has to have the Employee object then what are the alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable short answer is to maintain 3 separate maps for each of the 3 fields, with each one mapping from each field value to the list of employees with that value for the field.

To perform a lookup, retrieve the lists for each of the values that the user specified, and then (if you have more than one criteria) iterate through the *shortest* one to filter out employees that don't match the other criteria.

In the cases where you have more than one criteria, one of them has to be name or ID.  In real life, the lists for these fields will be very short, so you won't have to iterate through any large collections.

This solution essentially uses the maps as indexes and implements the query like a relational DB.  If you were to mention that in an interview, you would get extra points, but you'd need to be able to back it up.

Comment: I did suggest this when they asked if given a choice, how will you design ? However , they were hell bent on using the same Employee object to search on different fields.

Answer (score 0):

One of the neat things about Java 8 is the `Stream`s API.  With this new API, you an hold all of those `Employee` objects within just a normal `List` and walk away with the same results you were trying to achieve with multiple mapping objects with less overhead.

See, this API has a `.filter()` method that you can pass over a `List` that has been transformed into a `Stream` to only return objects that meet the criteria described in the body of the `filter`.

```
List<Employee> emps = getEmps();

List<Employee> matchedEmps = emps.stream().filter((e)->e.getID().equals(searchedID)).filter((e)->e.getName().equals(searchedName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see you can chain `filter`s to match multiple criteria, although it may be more efficient just to have all matching done in one filter:

```
ist<Employee> matchedEmps = emps.stream().filter((e)->{boolean matches = e.getID().equals(searchedID);return matches && e.getName().equals(searchedName);}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Well the map can be searched on the basis of just name , ID or date of joining. Now in this way you have to iterate over all the employee objects. I dont think that is a good use of Map.

Comment: @user3276247 This is true, however, if you have three maps each keyed with a different attribute, the difference may be negligible.  Another thing to note here is that the `Stream` api has a parallel implementation that can dramatically increase processing power and it is as easy as`emps.parallelStream().filter(...`

Comment: I get what you are saying. This is an efficient way to do in java8. Question was more to judge on design and hashing skills. So I think this won't be the answer I am looking for in the current context.

Comment: @user3276247 understood

Answer (score 0):

I would have a map with the Employee object as key and EmployeeDetails as value. I would get a get Collection of values from the map, create then a custom Comparator for each specific search, iterate through the values collection and use the comparator to compare the values. The search results should be added during the iteration in a results Collection.

Comment: If you have to iterate through the entire collection, then there's no reason to use a Map

Answer (score 0):

One way is create mapping with mapping Employee-EmployeeDetails then for search for a given employee id then you have to iterate over all key and search.The complexity will be O(N).

Second to improve the time complexity even in database we do indexing to avoid full scan.You can try  the similar thing here i.e create mapping id-Employee,email-Employee like this when add employee to main map also update to the index map.

Third if possible you can create a TRIE and at end node you can put employee.After getting the employee You can get employee details

Comment: Trie would have been useful if we know that search will always be in a specify way i.e name, date of joining , id or any such order. What if you create a trie using this structure and the user searches using date of joining first?

Comment: In any search when we create index we do know we are going to use that index because it is also have some pre-processing time complexity.Same with trie if you required it you can create because it has memeory and time complexity.